# How do I suppress an icon's highlight?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I just want to start off saying I'm new to web development; I'm a noob when it comes to HTML and CSS.

Having said that: I'm building a personal website, and I'm utilizing the [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) framework to style the site.

I have two icons present in the top navbar of my site--a *Contact me* icon, and a *Resume* button. Upon clicking these icons, there is a highlight that is unsightly.

[image]

How do I remove this? I want it so the "vertical" rectangle (from top of navbar to bottom of navbar) highlights--not the horizontal highlight on the icon.

Desired result when clicking the icon:
[image]

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <div class="nav-wrapper yellow lighten-2">
                <a href="#" class="page-title" style="color: #212121">Work Experience</a>
                <ul class="right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">
                            <i class="mdi-communication-message"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't get the highlight when I use it. Can you create a demo of it? http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/24L3gw8u/3/

Comment: @ManojKumar I can't seem to replicate it with all my CSS. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: It's likely the :focus style the browser applies. This is actually a usability and accessibility feature for those that may be navigating via the keyboard. You can remove it, but I'd advice against it.

Comment: @ManojKumar [On this site](http://aidanfollestad.com/contact), the issue isn't present--plus, it looks even nicer when clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following selector to your css file to override the hover property of the element.

```
<resume-selector>:hover,
<contact-me-selector>:hover {
    background-color:  <color-of-vertical-highlight>
}
```

I don't know (from the code you posted) what the selectors or desired color is, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple.

Create a generic class implementation named as "li-no-hover"

Set background property on :Hover selector.

HTML Code:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper deep-orange accent-4">
        <a href="" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li class="li-no-hover"><a><span class="btn">Login / SignUp</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS Code:

```
nav .nav-wrapper ul li.li-no-hover:hover {
  background-color: transparent; }
```

Note: If you want it the other way round, just move the no-hover from `<li>` to `<span>`.